# Help with itunes XML

Tags: xml, jsp, itunes

Im a new web developer trying to load some xml files into a JSP so that you can view them online. One particular file is giving me a lot of trouble, I keep getting this error message and I am unsure of what to do next

> The XML page cannot be displayed 
>   Cannot view XML input using style
>   sheet. Please correct the error and
>   then click the Refresh button, or try
>   again later.
>
> ---
>
> The system cannot locate the object
>   specified. Error processing resource
>   'http://www.apple.com/DTDs/%20%20%20PropertyList-:...

The xml file in question is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
    "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/
   PropertyList-: 1.0.dtd">
 <?xml-stylesheet href="itunesview.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
 <plist version="1.0">
 <dict>
   <key>Major Version</key><integer>1</integer>
   <key>Minor Version</key><integer>1</integer>
   <key>Application Version</key><string>4.9</string>
   <key>Music Folder</key><string>file://localhost/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/
   Test%20Name/My%20Documents/My%20Music/iTunes/iTunes%20Music/
   </string>
   <key>Library Persistent ID</key><string>45B7F87C7466C64A</string>
   <key>Tracks</key>
   <dict>
     <key>37</key>
     <dict>
       <key>Track ID</key><integer>37</integer>
       <key>Name</key><string>Thinking Of You</string>
       <key>Artist</key><string>Lenny Kravitz</string>
       <key>Composer</key><string>Lenny Kravitz/Lysa Trenier</string>
       <key>Album</key><string>5</string>
       <key>Genre</key><string>Pop/Funk</string>
       <key>Kind</key><string>MPEG audio file</string>
       <key>Size</key><integer>6141310</integer>
       <key>Total Time</key><integer>383764</integer>
       <key>Track Number</key><integer>32</integer>
       <key>Year</key><integer>1998</integer>
       <key>Date Modified</key><date>2005-06-08T20:04:06Z</date>
       <key>Date Added</key><date>2004-05-06T04:29:57Z</date>
       <key>Bit Rate</key><integer>128</integer>
       <key>Sample Rate</key><integer>44100</integer>
       <key>Comments</key><string>By ScazzI</string>
       <key>Play Count</key><integer>6</integer>
       <key>Play Date</key><integer>-1088231274</integer>
       <key>Play Date UTC</key><date>2005-08-13T05:00:22Z</date>
       <key>Track Type</key><string>File</string>
       <key>Location</key><string>file://localhost/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/Test%20Name/My%20Documents/My%20Music/Masheed/Lenny%20Kravitz%20-%20Thinking%20Of%20You.mp3/</string>
       <key>File Folder Count</key><integer>-1</integer>
       <key>Library Folder Count</key><integer>-1</integer>
     </dict>
     <key>132</key>
       <dict>
        <key>Track ID</key><integer>132</integer>
        <key>Name</key><string>Feel Good Inc.</string>
        <key>Artist</key><string>Gorillaz</string>
        <key>Album Artist</key><string>Gorillaz</string>
        <key>Composer</key><string>D. Jolicoeur/Gorillaz</string>
        <key>Album</key><string>Demon Days</string>
        <key>Genre</key><string>Electronica</string>
        <key>Kind</key><string>MPEG audio file</string>
        <key>Size</key><integer>8904387</integer>
        <key>Total Time</key><integer>221328</integer>
        <key>Track Number</key><integer>6</integer>
        <key>Year</key><integer>2005</integer>
        <key>Date Modified</key><date>2007-04-09T18:05:07Z</date>
        <key>Date Added</key><date>2007-08-10T13:41:11Z</date>
        <key>Bit Rate</key><integer>320</integer>
        <key>Sample Rate</key><integer>48000</integer>
        <key>Artwork Count</key><integer>1</integer>
        <key>Persistent ID</key><string>E71B365F40835349</string>
        <key>Track Type</key><string>File</string>
        <key>Location</key><string>file://localhost/D:/Documents%20and%20Settings/James/My%20Documents/My%20Music/My%20Playlists/../Gorillaz/2005.%20Demon%20Days/06.%20Feel%20Good%20Inc..mp3</string>
        <key>File Folder Count</key><integer>-1</integer>
        <key>Library Folder Count</key><integer>-1</integer>
  </dict> 
 </dict>
 </plist>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never seen a DTD inside XML declarations - maybe that is the problem.

It must be prior to all other statements

this line:

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
   "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/
  PropertyList-: 1.0.dtd">
```

should be the first - but the DTD uri seems to be invalid - best remove it - it does no good

Comment: Thanks! that seemed to correct the problem, I am now able to view it correctly!